# Disabling certain elements inside the list based on custom attribute value of list item

Tags: jquery

I have the following list

```
<ul id="sections">
<li data="section1">Section1 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section2">Section2 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section3">Section3 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section4">Section4 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section5">Section5 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section6">Section6 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section7">Section7 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section8">Section8 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
<li data="section9">Section9 <i class="icon-trash pull-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```

i need to add a class hide to `<i>` element inside section1, 3 & 9 alone.

What is the best way to do this with jQuery

I am trying with custom data attribute selector

```
$('li[data="section1"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of your options:

```
$('li[data="section1"] i, li[data="section3"] i, li[data="section9"] i').addClass('hide')
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/zapik/2/edit). Also, use some `data-*` attribute, not `data` alone.

Comment: Corrected so it does just that :-)

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks